# find distribution of the ratio of two normal r.v. with transformation U=X/Y V=Y

Tags: distributions, data-transformation

Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger (2nd ed) page 162 provides a way of finding the ratio of normal variables using U=X/Y and V=|Y|. I understand it.

But what if I use V=Y?

(I know it is not necessary to use partition here due to page 156. But using partition occurs naturally since U is not defined when $Y=0$)

now the partition becomes:
$$
A_1 = \{(x,y):y>0\}\\
A_2 = \{(x,y):y<0\}\\
A_0 = \{(x,y):y=0\}
$$
And the inverse transformation under either $A_1$ and $A_2$ is $x=uv$ and $y=v$

Jacobians from the two inverses are $J_1=J_2=v$. But note that $v=y>0$ in $A_1$ while $v=y<0$ in $A_2$.

Then the joint pdf for U,V becomes:
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v|+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v| \\= \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}v+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}(-v)=0
$$

What goes wrong? Thanks!

---

Thanks for the comments, I know what went wrong. Please see the answer below.

Comment: You forgot the indicator functions of $A_1$ and $A_2$!

Comment: I somehow understand what you mean. If there is an indicator, the 2nd term of the last equation vanish identically. But could you be more explicit on where am I supposed to add an indicator function?

Comment: The final equality is not valid: you can't just remove the absolute values.

Comment: In any case you should end up with $f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(u^2v^2+v^2)/2}|v|$ where $(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @whuber , you are right and thank you. But I still got a little problem. If I keep the absolute value and get $f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{|v|}{\pi}e^{-(u^2+1)v^2/2}$. And the marginal distribution of U is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{U,V}(u,v)dv = \frac{2}{\pi(u^2+1)}$. But the answer is half of it. Where I did wrong?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't provided the details.  When using the absolute value, though, don't forget that the map $v\to |v|$ is two-to-one.

Comment: @whuber The following is how I did it. Please have a look. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{U,V}(u,v)dv = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{|v|}{\pi}e^{-(u^2+1)v^2/2}dv = \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{-v}{\pi}e^{-(u^2+1)v^2/2}dv+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{v}{\pi}e^{-(u^2+1)v^2/2}dv=$$2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{v}{\pi}e^{-(u^2+1)v^2/2}dv=2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(u^2+1)z/2}dz=2\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2}{u^2+1}=\frac{2}{\pi(u^2+1)}$ (z=$v^2$)

Comment: You have defined $V=|Y|,$ which guarantees it is non-negative.  Thus, for $-\infty\lt v\lt0,$ it is necessarily the case that $f_{U,V}(u,v)=0.$  You don't seem to have used that information anywhere.

Comment: @whuber I defined V=Y... it is defined as absolute value in the book and I wanted to change that.

Comment: Why, then, did the absolute value $|v|$ appear in your integral?  When you get the wrong answer to a problem, and you *know* it's wrong, then the best way to find the mistake is to lay out your reasoning clearly and carefully, attempting to justify each step.

Answer (score 1):

$f_{U,V}(u,v)\neq0$ because I cannot remove the absolute value of v and offset each other (both of them are non-negative).

A deeper thought makes me realize that I cannot sum up these two terms because they have different domains on v. The first term is defined on $V=Y>0$ but the second term is defined on $V=Y<0$. Summation of functions requires all the functions defined on the same domain. This is a basic requirement.

This also solves the question I have in the comments, i.e., why the result is 2 times the correct answer. I cannot sum up the functions. Instead,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{U,V}(u,v)dv \\=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v_{\{v>0\}}|+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v_{\{v<0\}}|\bigg)dv \\=
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v_{\{v>0\}}|dv+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}|v_{\{v<0\}}|dv \\=
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}vdv+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(uv)^2}e^{-v^2/2}(-v)dv \\=
\frac{1}{\pi(u^2+1)}, -\infty<u<+\infty
$$

Through this extension on example 4.3.6, it is clear that using transformation $V=|Y|$ is simpler. And we do not need to worry about the issue occurred above because both terms are defined on the same domain, $V=|Y|>0$.